# Remove config files of any package

Tags: apt, package-management, configuration, dependencies, purge

How would I remove the config files of any package, or do `apt-get purge` and re-install it **without** removing any of its dependencies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dpkg :

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all (name of package)
```

Comment: welcome any time

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo apt-get remove pkg`.
Replace pkg with the package name you want to remove and it will leave the dependencies alone. Then use `sudo apt-get install pkg` to re-install the packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it and apt "threatens" to remove many other packages (its dependencies) and even then, it wouldn't remove the config files, would it?

Comment: To remove the config files, use `purge` instead of `remove`